# Connecting to a MSSQL on OS X running MAMP PRO

Tags: php, sql-server, mamp, osx-elcapitan

**EDIT**: I have not found the solution, instead a virtual machine was created with centOS where the extensions needed would load. If this can help someone in the future, that's fantastic.

Versions: PHP5.6, MSSQL 2008, OS x El Capitan

I'm trying to query a MSSQL database to compare results with a MySQL database. I can query the MySQL db without issue, I cannot query the MSSQL db. I've installed freetds, odbc, autoconf, followed multiple tutorials including:

- http://davehiren.blogspot.com/2015/07/mamp-install-mssql-extension.html
- https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/wiki/Mac-setup-to-connect-to-a-MS-SQL-Server
- http://blog.andyhunt.info/2013/11/29/php-mssql-pdo_dblib-freetds-support-on-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/

I've also tried using Propelorm without success.

Checks:
 - myssql.so is in the extensions folder and is being called in my php.ini.
 - I've tried running a try/catch on my 500 error, no good.
 - apache and php logs don't show anything in regards to the page I'm loading or the service in general.
 - php.info show the correct extensions file and the correct directory to call the extension, a search in the page did not spit back anything with "mssql" or "pdo_dblib".

My next course of action is to create a virtual machine running Ubuntu to test the script but I would like to be able to develop on my host machine.

Looking at the php.ini for php5.6.31 (version being used by MAMP PRO):

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.31/conf/php.ini

 421 ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
 422 extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/"

 531 ; Extensions
 532 
 533 ;extension=apcu.so
 534 extension=mssql.so
 535 extension=pdo_dblib.so
 536 extension=imap.so
 537 extension=mcrypt.so
 538 extension=gettext.so
 539 extension=pgsql.so
 540 extension=pdo_pgsql.so
 541 
 542 ;extension=imagick.so
 543 ;extension=tidy.so
 544 extension=oauth.so
```

Taking a look in the extensions folder, we can see the mssql.so file:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/

apcu.so                         mcrypt.so                       tidy.so
gettext.so                      memcached.so                    uploadprogress.so
igbinary.so                     mssql.so                        xcache.so
imagick.so                      oauth.so                        xdebug.so
imap.so                         opcache.so                      yaml.so
ioncube_loader_dar_5.6.so       pdo_pgsql.so                    yaz.so
ioncube_loader_dar_5.6_ts.so    pgsql.so
```

I'm not sure what else to include, let me know in the comments and I will update the questions.

```
 23   $mssql_link = mssql_connect($custom_mssql_host, $custom_mssql_user, $custom_mssql_pass, $custom_mssql_db);
 24   if (!$mssql_link) {
 25     die('Could not connect to MSSQL database: ' . mssql_error());
 26     exit;
 27   }
 28   if(!mssql_select_db($custom_mssql_db)) {
 29     die('Could not select MSSQL database: ' . mssql_error());
 30     exit;
 31   }
 46   $query2 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM table2");
 47   $result2 = mssql_query($query1);
 48   if(!$query1) {
 49     die('Could not query:' .mssql_error());
 50   }
```

Comment: What does "cannot query" mean? Do you get an error message (turn off "simple" errors so you can get something a little more useful than a generic 500)? After doing what? What is the error message exactly? Where is SQL Server 2008 running? Have you verified that the service is running and that you can connect to it with other means?

Comment: @AaronBertrand , "cannot query" should probably read "cannot connect". I changed 'display_error = Off' to 'On' however the page comes up blank with the 500 network error and nothing in the apache log, the PHP log returns "Call to undefined function mssql_connect()" - I've updated my question with the code I'm using. I can access the db using an application SQLPro for MSSQL, it is up and running. SQL Server 2008 is running on a remote computer I can access using Microsoft Remote Desktop.

Comment: Where is `$custom_mssql_host` defined? Have you verified it contains what you expect?

Comment: @AaronBertrand it is defined at the top of the file and is correct, I've verified the credentials using SQLPro for MSSQL.

Comment: Well you're making it very hard for any of us to help troubleshoot. You need to determine what that 500 error is hiding.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I would very much like to make it easy for you! I tried running a try/catch to see if I could gather more intel but it doesn't even delay the 500. If there's an alternative method you'd recommend I would be happy to oblige. The closest I've gotten to an answer is that the mssql, pdo, and sqlsrv extensions are not loading.